# How to kill the "Default" desktop widget on KDE Plasma desktop?

Tags: kde5

This "Default" widget is hanging out on my desktop and both left- and right-click don't tell me what it is or how to get rid of it. (Not so easy to search for either.)

[image: Default]

Comment: The answer was already given here: https://superuser.com/questions/317603/how-to-disable-top-left-hotspot-corner-in-kde

Comment: @noraj this has nothing to do with screen edges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is the "desktop toolbox".

1. Right-click on Desktop and click "Configure Desktop"
2. Tab to "Tweaks", uncheck "Show the desktop toolbox", and Apply

[image: Tweaks]

Comment: I have been doing this on multiple computers since kubuntu 16.04 and on kubuntu 18.04, but every time I log in, the desktop toolbox reasserts itself. How can I make this stick across sessions?